# how to access wso2 identity server UserInformationRecoveryService api for multiple tenants

Tags: wso2-identity-server

while accessing wso2 identity server UserInformationRecoveryService api credentials provided is that of super tenant admin credentials. When tried to recover password for a user for a tenant following exception occurs:

```
org.wso2.carbon.identity.base.IdentityException: Failed access to unauthorized tenant domain
```

Is it mandatory to use each tenant's admin credentials to recover a password. Is there any way to use super tenant admin credentials for API access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is available in  5.1.0 SNAPSHOT version. 
Using super admin credentials while accessing UserInformationRecoveryService api helps to reset password for tenant users.